# Слайд-шоу на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

Ребят, всем привет.

Подскажите, как реализовать. Есть картинка размером 1910 px. Хочу сделать, чтобы под каждое разрешение экрана она обрезалась, высота оставалась прежней. Как это сделать?
Ниже принтскрин этой картинки. Сейчас есть внизу полоса прокрутки, хотя надо, чтобы она обрезалась.

Спасибо!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<div class="img"></div>
```

css:

```
div.img {
background-image: url(urltoimage);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top center;
width:100%;
height NNNpx;
}
```

Где:

urltoimage - путь к картинке

NNNpx - высота картинки

Comment: К сожалению, картинка будет вставляться через тег img.

Comment: тогда центрируйте картинку, и делайте ей overflow:hidden;, должно помочь.

Comment: Решил с помощью 
max-height:395px;
max-width:100%;

Comment: Разве при этом она не уменьшается пропорционально?

Comment: @duddeniska, проблема того, что картинка вставляется в HTML, решается инлайновым стилем:

`<div style="background-image: url(urltoimage);"></div>`

Только не забудьте к диву применить в CSS те стили, что написал  @Crus.